# Deleted synced Active Directory VM - Can't remove users fromAzure Active Directory now

Tags: azure, entra-id

In my Azure test subscription I had an Active Direcory VM synchronizing to Azure Active Directory via Azure AD connect for educaional purpose.
I simply deleted the AD VM and now I have the chaos.
I can't delete users in Azure AD due to the source missing.
I would love to reset the whole network to start over, but I'm not able to so far, right?

Have a nice day!
Achim

Comment: See the steps for Cause 1 in this article - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2619062/you-can-t-manage-or-remove-objects-that-were-synchronized-through-the

Comment: The problem is more complicated. I had to add a new user via Portal with Global Administrator role and different domain of kind *.onmicrosoft.com to be able to run the needed commands to stop synching. Now I am waiting if I will be able to delete all users from the AD VM now...